# SwiftUI how to pass a core data object details to a Detail view

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have view that displays rows of contact (core data entities). Upon selection of a row, I would like to display the details of the selected contact in a DetailView. How can I pass the contact.uniqueID which is a attribute in Contact entity to the DetailView? Then I can pull the data of the Contact entity from core data and display its details. Is there a better way than this, pl let me lnow.

```
struct ContentView: View {
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(contacts) { contact in
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView()
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(contact.firstName! + " " + contact.lastName!)
                }
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Contacts")
    ToolbarItem {
        NavigationLink {
            AddContactView()
        } label: {
            Label("Add Contact", systemImage: "plus")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
    
}

}
```

Edited:

```
NavigationView {
     List {
         ForEach(contacts) { contact in
         
             NavigationLink {
                DisplayContactView(contact: contact)
             }
        }
    }
 }
```

Then in DisplayView

```
struct DisplayView: View {
init(contact: Contact) {
    _contact = StateObject(wrappedValue:contact)
}
var body: some View
{ 
    NavigationView
    {
        VStack
        {
            TextField("Full Name", text: $contact.firstName!)
        }
    }
  }


}
```

I get  error: on TextField

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Binding' error: on TextField

Comment: Pass the whole object instead, no reason to re-fetch something you already have access to.

Comment: Pass the whole object and wrap in “@ObservedObject”

Comment: @vrao - for readability, please [edit] your question with additional information, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Edited the code above in the original posting with the changes I made by adding ObservableObject, and still get some errors.

Comment: Observable object gave me lot of errors, so used StateObject lesser erros, but I get syntax error -Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Binding' error: on TextField
Edited code in original posting

Comment: StateObject is for initializing objects  which is done by FetchRequest in this case. Search for the new error on SO you’ll find plenty of solutions.

Comment: lorem ipsum: 
I did that and it worked.
extension Binding {
     func toUnwrapped<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T>  {
        Binding<T>(get: { self.wrappedValue ?? defaultValue }, set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 })
    }
}
TextField("Full Name", text:  $contact.firstName.toUnwrapped(defaultValue: ""))
I would like to accept your suggestion since it was far easier and takes care of error as compared to Malhal's suggestion.

How can accept your suggestion and close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way - because core data uses an object it already has an ID which is its pointer so you don't need to look it up, e.g.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//
//  Created by Malcolm Hall on 28/04/2023.
//
// Demonstrates modifying the default Xcode template from NavigationView to NavigationStack

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
                Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            //Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```